# Cannot Start Eclipse. JVM terminated. Exit code=13. (RHEL)

Tags: linux, eclipse, rhel

Working on getting eclipse running on RHEL 5. I extracted the tarball, but I am getting the following errors.

This is the error I get:

```
JVM terminated. Exit code=13
/software/java64/jdk1.6.0_24/bin/java
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m
-jar /privdir/iasr160/software/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20130327-1440.jar
-os linux
-ws gtk
-arch x86
-showsplash /privdir/iasr160/software/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.platform_4.3.2.v20140221-1700/splash.bmp
-launcher /privdir/iasr160/software/eclipse/eclipse
-name Eclipse
--launcher.library /privdir/iasr160/software/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_1.1.200.v20140116-2212/eclipse_1508.so
-startup /privdir/iasr160/software/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20130327-1440.jar
--launcher.appendVmargs
-exitdata 410006
-product org.eclipse.epp.package.cpp.product
-vm /software/java64/jdk1.6.0_24/bin/java
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m
-jar /privdir/iasr160/software/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20130327-1440.jar
```

This is what my eclipse.ini looks like:

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20130327-1440.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_1.1.200.v20140116-2212
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.cpp.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vm
/software/java64/jdk1.6.0_24/bin/java
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m
```

What additional details are needed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have eclipse for a 32-bit jvm. See your error message,it says -arch x86. Try installing eclipse 64-bits

Comment: Thank you.. It solved my issue. Eclipse that I was given was of 32-bit and my java 8 was of 64-bit. Installing 64-bit eclipse resolved my issue and now I can start eclipse.